# is it possible to use same scoreloop leaderboard for two applications

Tags: android, leaderboard, scoreloop

In my Android application, I'm using the scoreloop leader board, but the thing is that I want to use same leader board for another application. I want that the score of these two application should be submitted at same leader board.

How can I do that? Is it possible? Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have the same leaderboard by using the same ID for both apps (games).

Comment: u r right Beenish.I think i have to use same scoreloop.properties file also...btw +1 for ur response.:)